# Why can't I use middleware in my express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, jwt

I am creating an API, so I want to add a user system and validate access to the API.

This would be the middleware for validation:

```
'use strict'

const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const moment = require('moment');
const config = require('../settings/config');

function isAuth(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers.authotization) {
        return res.status(403).send({
            message: `No tiene autorizacion`
        })
    }
    const token = req.headers.authotization.split(" ")[1];
    const payload = jwt.decode(token, user, config.token.secret_token);

    if (payload.exp <= moment().unix()) {
        return res.status(401).send({
            message: 'El token ha expirado'
        })

        req.user = payload.sub;
        next();

    }
}

module.exports = isAuth;
```

while this would be the route:

```
    'use strict'
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const auth = require('../middlewares/auth');

    router.get('/', auth.isAuth, (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: `Tienes acceso`
        })
    })
```

on the other hand, this is my main application settings (app.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
const config = require('./config')

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Routes variables
const productRouter = require('../routes/product');
const privateRouter = require('../routes/private');

// Routes uses
app.use('/api/product', productRouter);
app.use('/private', privateRouter);

app.listen(config.app.port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${config.app.port}`)
})

module.exports = app;
```

I am getting this error:

> D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
>           throw new Error(msg);
>           ^
>
> Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object
>   Undefined]
>       at Route. [as get] (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
>       at Function.proto. [as get] (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:510:19)
>       at Object. (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\routes\private.js:6:8)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at Object. (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\settings\app.js:15:23)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

And sometimes this line is added at the top of error:

> (node:3092) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners > added to [Bus]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

After reading the answers, I edit my question. I have placed only **auth** and not auth.isAuth and I am getting the following error:

> D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
>         throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
>         ^
>
> TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a
>   Object
>       at Function.use (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
>       at Function. (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Function.use (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
>       at Object. (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\settings\app.js:20:5)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at Object. (D:\api-rest-carlos-azaustre\index.js:3:13)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Does anybody know what is it due to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports = isAuth;` means you're *only* exporting the function and nothing else. That means when you do `const auth = require('../middlewares/auth');`, `auth` is the actual function, not an object containing `isAuth` as a property.

So, doing `router.get('/', auth, (req, res) => {` should work, instead of `auth.isAuth` which is invalid.

Learn more about modules here: https://js.evie.dev/modules

Comment: I get a new error when I put that. I have added it to the end of the question.

Comment: @DiesanRomero I have a feeling the issue is no longer related to the function, but rather in your routers. Perhaps you're missing the module.exports in your route files, as each route file needs to export the router. Here's a tutorial on the subject of how they should be properly formed: https://scotch.io/tutorials/keeping-api-routing-clean-using-express-routers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you export the function with this code: `module.exports = isAuth;`

But then you call use it like this: `auth.isAuth`

Assuming you're doing something like `const auth = require('./bin/auth.js');` or whatever

`auth` would be the function itself -- there will be no `isAuth` property.

So you should try this:

```
router.get('/', auth, (req, res) => {
```

You haven't posted your entire code, so this is just a best guess.

Comment: I get a new error when I put that. I have added it to the end of the question. Please tell me what more information you need so you can help me. I will be very pleased to place it and receive your help.